# Обработка ajax запроса

Tags: php, ajax

Добрый вечер. Такая ситуация, на странице есть форма:

```
<form id="quesform" action="ad_content/anslib.php" method="post">
<input id="r1" type="radio" name="q1" value="a">
<label class="radio-helper" for="r1">Вариант 1</label>
<input id="r2" type="radio" name="q1" value="b">
<label class="radio-helper" for="r2">Вариант 2</label>
<input id="r3" type="radio" name="q1" value="c">
<label class="radio-helper" for="r3">Вариант 3</label>
<input id="r4" type="radio" name="q1" value="d">
<label class="radio-helper" for="r4">Вариант 4</label>
<button class="btn" type="submit" name="sandAns">Проверить</button>
</form>
```

у формы есть обработчик в виде ajax запроса:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#quesform').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          url:'ad_content/anslib.php',
          type:'post',
          date:  $('#quesform').serialize(),
          success: function(result){
            alert(result);
          }

        });
    });
  });
```

Вот собственно обработчик(php):

```
if($_POST['q1'] == 'a'){
    echo "Правильный ответ";
  }else{
    echo "Неправильный ответ";
  }
```

Какое бы значение на форме я не выбрал  в итоге js выводит сообщение о том что ответ неправильный. Я совсем не очень с ajax, практически сегодня только познакомился, прошу помощи)

Comment: опечатка - dat**a**: $('#quesform').serialize(),

Comment: Добавьте перед своей проверкой `var_dump($_POST)` и посмотрите, что внутри. Параметра `q1` там точно нет

Comment: @Igor, Боже, я идиот, спасибо) и извините)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас опечатка в оформлении запроса. 
Поменяйте  date на data